# Gevent installation error in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, gevent

Tried installing gevent using pip install gevent and also tried compiling from source. Both the times the installation stopped because of the following error.

/usr/local/include/evhttp.h:223: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘ev_int64_t’

i have libevent installed in /usr/local/lib and its being picked up during installation. Any help would be highly appreciated.

-Avinash

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error as well. I believe it is due to a conflict between libev and libevent (in my case, libev-4.11 and libevent-1.4.14b). libev replaces `/usr/local/include/event.h` and `/usr/local/include/evutil.h` with its own version of those files, and trying to compile gevent with the versions from libev results in the error:

`/usr/local/include/evhttp.h:223: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘ev_int64_t’`

After removing libev and reinstalling libevent, I was able to install gevent using easy_install.